# WebSocket Exception Error, Unable to connect to host in React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make get the [Static PDF in React Native using React-Native-Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940902/static-pdf-in-react-native-using-react-native-pdf?noredirect=1#comment116588654_65940902) to work and I compiled in Xcode and got the following error:

```
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Inspector
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Preferences
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin React
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Network
2021-01-28 12:22:26.525520-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] Connection 1: received failure notification
2021-01-28 12:22:26.525713-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] Connection 1: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-01-28 12:22:26.525876-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] Connection 1: encountered error(12:8)
2021-01-28 12:22:26.528408-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741964] Task <E95DC159-8401-4A5B-ADC8-BA12FAD34471>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-01-28 12:22:26.532663-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741964] Task <E95DC159-8401-4A5B-ADC8-BA12FAD34471>.<1> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001524480 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <E95DC159-8401-4A5B-ADC8-BA12FAD34471>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <E95DC159-8401-4A5B-ADC8-BA12FAD34471>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}
2021-01-28 12:22:26.540045-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1740879] [native] Running application reactNativePdfSample ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2021-01-28 12:22:26.598180-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741962] Connection 2: received failure notification
2021-01-28 12:22:26.598360-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741962] Connection 2: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2021-01-28 12:22:26.598479-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741962] Connection 2: encountered error(12:8)
2021-01-28 12:22:26.600421-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] Task <1FB14047-8A22-4ACB-8FC4-300F26092591>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2021-01-28 12:22:26.600970-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] Task <1FB14047-8A22-4ACB-8FC4-300F26092591>.<2> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001514060 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1FB14047-8A22-4ACB-8FC4-300F26092591>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <1FB14047-8A22-4ACB-8FC4-300F26092591>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}
2021-01-28 12:22:26.610525-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C3] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:26.610677-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c54000 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:26.673472-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741964] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C4] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:26.673632-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741964] TCP Conn 0x600002c40b00 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:26.675362-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741964] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:26.878351-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C5] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:26.878525-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c449a0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:26.915372-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] Require cycle: node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/Blob.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2021-01-28 12:22:26.917529-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] Require cycle: node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/XMLHttpRequest.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2021-01-28 12:22:26.920051-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] Require cycle: node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/Fetch.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2021-01-28 12:22:27.191270-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] Running "reactNativePdfSample" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
2021-01-28 12:22:28.019503-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] [Error: Load pdf failed. path=/Users/brandonsmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47395DCD-9D3F-4159-B901-EC1282C9F9E3/data/Containers/Data/Application/20516689-CC18-4BEA-B04F-0E2CB342E865/Library/Caches/7d778ad782c0541d54b32a64a872ac0b1cc56f56.pdf]
2021-01-28 12:22:28.020549-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] [Error: Load pdf failed. path=/Users/brandonsmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47395DCD-9D3F-4159-B901-EC1282C9F9E3/data/Containers/Data/Application/20516689-CC18-4BEA-B04F-0E2CB342E865/Library/Caches/7d778ad782c0541d54b32a64a872ac0b1cc56f56.pdf]
2021-01-28 12:22:28.021108-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741988] [javascript] [Error: Load pdf failed. path=/Users/brandonsmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47395DCD-9D3F-4159-B901-EC1282C9F9E3/data/Containers/Data/Application/20516689-CC18-4BEA-B04F-0E2CB342E865/Library/Caches/7d778ad782c0541d54b32a64a872ac0b1cc56f56.pdf]
2021-01-28 12:22:28.759888-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C6] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:28.760195-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] TCP Conn 0x600002c4c0b0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:28.762019-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C7] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:28.762250-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] TCP Conn 0x600002c4dce0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:28.762544-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:30.761528-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C8] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:30.761748-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] TCP Conn 0x600002c4dce0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:30.768705-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C9] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:30.769012-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c40a50 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:30.771215-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C10] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:30.771879-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c48840 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:30.772328-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:32.784335-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C14] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:32.784507-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c58160 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:32.789985-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C15] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:32.790120-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741959] TCP Conn 0x600002c44b00 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:32.790396-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:34.982556-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C20] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:34.982797-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c44c60 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:34.984929-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C21] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:34.985385-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] TCP Conn 0x600002c40a50 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:34.985652-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:36.970080-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C22] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:36.970293-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c48840 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:36.986485-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C26] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:36.986667-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c48bb0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:36.993208-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C27] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:36.993513-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c58160 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:36.996436-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C28] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:36.996848-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c54000 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:36.997240-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:38.991398-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C34] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:38.991542-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c48840 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:39.000622-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C36] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:39.000790-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c40bb0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:39.006689-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C37] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:39.007033-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] TCP Conn 0x600002c4dc30 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:39.009479-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C38] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:39.009860-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] TCP Conn 0x600002c44c60 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:39.010161-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
2021-01-28 12:22:41.022651-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C47] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:41.022765-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c41760 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:41.048234-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C50] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:41.048746-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741957] TCP Conn 0x600002c58160 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:41.053293-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C51] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-01-28 12:22:41.053934-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741956] TCP Conn 0x600002c4dce0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2021-01-28 12:22:41.054515-0500 reactNativePdfSample[19106:1741958] [native] Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Websocket exception Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8}
```

How can I fix this?